# Access VBA wont input date into date field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need some help with this code which i cant get over for many hours now.

Im making a db used for ducment handling and here i need a date for the newly uploaded document.

```
If MsgBox("Mai dátummal mehet?", vbYesNo, "Verzió") = vbYes Then
    db.Execute ("UPDATE Dokumentumok SET Verzió = Date() WHERE Jelölés='" & Me.Jelölés & "'")
Else
    version = InputBox("Add meg a dátumot éééé.hh.nn.", "Verzió", Date)
    version = Replace(version, ".", ". ")
    If IsDate(version) Then
        db.Execute ("UPDATE Dokumentumok SET Verzió ='" & CDate(version) & "' WHERE Jelölés='" & Me.Jelölés & "'")
    Else
        MsgBox "Rossz formátum, mentve mai dátummal"
        db.Execute ("UPDATE Dokumentumok SET Verzió = Date() WHERE Jelölés='" & Me.Jelölés & "'")
    End If
End If
```

First msgbox asks if it goes with todays date, if yes, then it updates the specific date which works just fine.
If not, inputbox asks for the date.
I live in Hungary, defualt date format is YYYY.MM.DD. here, in access by default it is YYYY. MM. DD. - there is space between them, dont know if it matters

So far i have tried to input with the following formats with lets say October 20, 2015:

- 2015.10.20.
- 2015. 10. 20.
- 10.20.2015
- 10. 20. 2015
- 20.10.2015
- 20. 10. 2015
- 10/20/2015
- 20/10/2015

Even trying with a small code in a module with everything set to manual to update that date field in the table, through isdate() check
Every type passed date check but still either code runs and date field remains empty or i get error Too few parameters, expected 1 if i try sate with "\" instead of "."

```
version = "2015.10.20."
version = Mid(version, 6, 6) & Left(version, 4)
version = Replace(version, ".", "/")
If IsDate(version) Then
db.Execute ("UPDATE Dokumentumok SET Verzió = #" & version & "# WHERE Jelölés=E2")
End If
```

This one gives error missing operator in query expression '2015. 10. 20.'

```
    version = "2015. 10. 20. "
    If IsDate(CDate(version)) Then
    db.Execute ("UPDATE Dokumentumok SET Verzió = " & CDate(version) & " WHERE Jelölés=E2")

End If
```

This one syntax error in date in query expression '#2015. 10. 20.'

```
db.Execute ("UPDATE Dokumentumok SET Verzió = #" & CDate(version) & "# WHERE Jelölés=E2")
```

I have tried many combinations of variable between '' or ##, values between '', ##, date variables, formatted string variables etc.

Guys, I cant seem to make it work on my own I need an help with it.

Thanks in advance,
Kristof

Comment: have you got `dim version as date`? and cant you use `format ()` to change the date?

Comment: If your standard is 'YYYY.MM.DD' than I don't think you want spaces in your date. However, I just tried this in the US and it doesn't care about the spaces. Try adding this line and see what happens: Debug.Print Format(Version, "mm.dd.yyyy")

Comment: could it be the last point in the string? A date normally reads as "2015.10.20" not "2015.10.20." In the provided code snippet you replace the last point to "/" which leads to "2015/10/20/" which isn't a date either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date format that all (I hope) international Access versions understand, is the ISO format YYYY-MM-DD.

And the date delimiter is `#`

So with the Format function:

```
"UPDATE Dokumentumok SET Verzió = #" & Format(version, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#"
```

Comment: Thanks Andre, this version of formating worked. Funny it still displays it as yyyy. mm. dd.  in the database.

Comment: @KristofMolnar: That's normal - date display is by default always the localized format. And the internal storage isn't influenced by the UPDATE format, in the database it's always an Access date.